# Locale.preferredLanguages returns en first sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, locale

When calling `Locale.preferredLanguages` sometimes it returns `en` first when I have multiple languages please see the image below.

[image]

You can see on the left my order is Spanish then English but the array `Locale.preferredLanguages` is returning `English, Spanish`.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: What is the base language in your app?

Comment: The base language is english. But if I delete the app and re run spanish comes first since my device is set to Spanish. then re running sometimes english comes first

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Locale.preferredLanguages doesn't say anything about the order of the languages returned. That seems absurd, but there it is.

It looks like the `Bundle` class' `preferredLocalizations(from:forPreferences:)` function **does** order it's responses in user preference order⁽¹⁾, so it sounds like you may need to pass in an array of all the locales your app supports to your Bundle and have it give you the results in user-preference order.

---

⁽¹⁾ To quote the docs: "Return Value: An array of locale identifiers, ordered according to user preference."

Comment: This only returns english

Comment: It limits itself to the localizations you have added to your app. If you only support English, that's all you'll get back.